# Which help pages can be changed, by a site's community moderator?

Tags: support, help-center, moderator-abilities, site-specific

Each site's help center contains a number of help pages.  Which of these can be edited for a specific site by a community moderator on that site?

(To be clear, I am asking about ♦-moderators, not community managers or Stack Exchange employees.)

Comment: Any point to ask if you've already found the dupe? (just can't get it how would you find it so fast otherwise...)

Comment: @nicael, thanks for asking!  It took more searching than I thought should be necessary to find the answer (and didn't turn up in my initial searches), so I thought it might be used to others to have another version that's phrased in another way and might pop up in search.  However if people feel this is unhelpful I'll gladly delete this post.